# Multiple instances or windows of Lightroom opened for photo reorganization

Tags: lightroom, file-management

I am new to lightroom (Mac) and had been trying to migrate from using acdsee pro inside of a virtual windows machine. The workflow I am tying to achieve used to involve opening two acdsee browser/manage windows(vertically tiled). One showing my family events folder collection and one showing my download folder (with many imported on folders). I would create a new event folder or navigate into one, switch window, select bunch of photos and drag and drop into the other window, navigate up, and repeat the process until of my imported photo are organized.

My problem doubt this with lightroom is that I have too many folders in my events collection and to scroll up and down in he folder panel to find or to create events is just a nightmare since I can't keep my selection of imported photos easily while navigating.

Am I doing this wrong and there is a better solution? My main issue really the quantity of photo since I have been accumulating imported photo but not really organizing anything for quite sometime (three kids will leave you with little time for managing their photos).

Thanks for your help. 
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are wanting to do is select photos and create a new folder that is comprised of the selected images, LR will do that very easily. Select them then create a new folder and it will give you the option to include the selected images in the new folder. If you want to then add additional photos after that, select some new ones and drag them into the folder. All of this can be done from the library module and is very typical usage.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. My only complaint now is that I miss the easier (in my opinion) folder navigation using lists compared to for the folder navigation panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you import the files from sub-folders, you can have Lightroom import them all at the same time.  If you tell it to leave the files at their current location, you will then be able to bulk select the images that are in each folder (after import) and apply keywords or add them to Lightroom collections (or both).